# class HttpTransport has no attribute '_HttpTransport__get_request_url' python error

Tags: python-2.7

I am getting the following error "class HttpTransport has no attribute '_HttpTransport__get_request_url'" from the python built-in files, while calling the one of the API's mutate method

I don't know which library to upgrade or what to do.Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I happened to run into same issue while using **googleads** module, it seems the mentioned class **HttpTransport** belongs to **suds**.transport.http, while the method **__get_request_url** is specific for **suds-jurko** package.

I suggest to uninstall both suds and suds-jurko packages first.

```
pip uninstall suds-jurko
pip uninstall suds
```

After that reinstall them in following order:

```
pip install suds
pip install suds-jurko
```

Comment: What if you're installing from a requirements file? How did you figure this out?